# Build by VSCode C++ project developed in Eclipse

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a large project in linux that I wrote in Eclipse C++. I need to build the project for Raspbian- and the only way to do it that I found- is moving source code to Raspberry Pi and compile /debug remotely by using VSCode. The problem is that I don't know how I can do it - if I simply open directory, VSCode can not compile/debug it automatically. ( I'm new in VSCode)

Comment: VSCode is an IDE that comes without a build system. You need to handle the building process manually (e.g.: CMake, a Makefile, whatever Eclipse uses, ...)

Comment: By default VSCode will create a task to create an executable out of the single active file this is not what you want with some large library. Your best bet likely is to use whatever build method that you used in Eclipse.

Comment: Also you can install Eclipse in raspberry pi and I believe do your remote debug. I searched and found some info for that.

Comment: It is a problem to install eclipse in RaPI because it is headless. I can't find- how I can install only server for remote debugging?

Comment: Can't you use ssh into the raspberry pi and install via the shell? Or doesn't it install the server component?